# Cloud computing: when is the effort for using docker justified?

Tags: python, docker

I have a very long running python script, that cannot be parallelized (so it is single threaded = running only with one process).

- This job runs several days on my own computer.
- It does not benefit from any GPU support.
- For analysis and parameter optimization, I assume to run this job several times; perhaps 10 - 20 times with each time different parameters.
- As my own existing computer ressources are limited, I would like to use a powerful cloud CPU for this task.
- If I realize that the cloud CPUs are really much faster than my own CPU, I probably will migrate the job from e.g. AWS EC2 (Amazon Web Services) to a cheaper flat rate solution like Hetzner.

With this use case: does it make sense to put my setup in a docker container?

Or does this task not justify the effort for engineering and taking the learning curve in docker / docker compose etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for sure you don't need to use docker for that, because of some elements that I will list here:

- Docker use is justified for using in encapsulated environment, to obtain security and mostly a controlled access between containers processes.
- Another common attraction to Docker is the Continuous Integration/Replication aspects of container development, it is really good to create Docker containers to scale using Kubernetes or easy deployment using Jenkins, for example.
- You can read more about it here: https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/containers/when-and-why-to-use-docker/

Now, since your application does not need that, Docker is not the way. And another suggestion, if you need to run it multiple times with only parameter difference between those executions, it is really good for you to parallel it to enjoy a powerful CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Docker will make it much easier for you to *run* your application in the cloud in the sense that, you will be able to switch machines much easier.  In addition, it will make it easy to run it *cheaper*, because you won't have to spend alot of time spinning up your VMs, and can cheaply and easily spin VMs down, knowing that only *docker run* and no specific python or yum install steps have to be done to bootstrap the program.